# T-SQL stored procedure with dateadd fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, race-condition, dateadd

Seemingly simple part of my stored procedure appears to be failing, a date comparison. I am looking for the oldest order that is more than 5 minutes old to begin processing it.

The stored procedure is called by a python program to get the order number and begin processing it. Each touch of the order modifies `o.chg_date`, potentially extending the 5 minutes delay. There are times in the order creation process where the sales person will merge two orders. They need this 5 minute window to do so.

This is a simplified version of the stored procedure, but typical of the other where clauses.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Next_Order] 
AS
    SELECT TOP 1 o.order_id
    FROM orders o (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        o.order_state = 4               -- ready to be processed
        AND o.order_status <> 3         -- not a deleted order
        AND o.items > 0                 -- not an empty order
        AND o.chg_date < DATEADD(mi, -5, GETDATE())     -- 5 minute delay after ready
    ORDER BY
        o.chg_date
```

Problem: out of a dozen orders, two will get processed within 5 - 10 seconds.

Am I using the `DATEADD` function incorrectly? It does work 80% of the time. And I cannot get it to fail by simply running the code in SSMS.

The only other thing I can think of is that there is a race condition where the `order_state = 4` and `chg_date` has not been updated yet. Any suggestions for a race condition resolution?

`order_state` is updated by code. `chg_date` is updated by a trigger.

Comment: Your date add is subtracting 5 minutes from current time, so at 12:40  your query will use 12:35 in your date check and pull anything of a chg_date that is earlier than that.

Comment: Correct. An order that was ready at 12:36 will have to wait another minute to be processed. Once processed, the order_state will increment to 5.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'fail', what happens when it 'fails'?

Comment: The history file shows that some orders are being processed within 10 seconds of the order_state becoming = 4, which is tracked. This means that the o.chg_date comparison failed, no delay was felt. The order should not have been processed.
When I took just the query out of the SP and ran it in SSMS, it never once presented an order that did not have the full 5 minute delay.

Comment: I think you have race conditions and may need to investigate exclusive locks or a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
if object_id(N'TempDB.dbo.#orders') is not null
    drop table #orders;

--this time is too new (papa bear)
Select
    1 As Order_id
    ,4 As Order_state
    ,1 As Order_status
    ,11 As Items
    ,sysdatetime() As Chg_date
into #orders
union All
--this time is too old (momma bear)
Select
    2 As Order_id
    ,4 As Order_state
    ,1 As Order_status
    ,11 As Items
    ,dateadd(hour,-1,sysdatetime()) As Chg_date
union all
--this time is just right (baby bear)
Select
    3 As Order_id
    ,4 As Order_state
    ,1 As Order_status
    ,11 As Items
    ,dateadd(minute,-6,sysdatetime()) As Chg_date;

-----------------------only copy bottom section into your stored proc-----------------------------
with top_order as
(
    Select
        order_id
        ,Chg_date
        ,row_number() over (order by chg_date desc) as Row_num
    From
        #orders O (Nolock)
    Where
        O.Order_state = 4                   -- ready to be processed
        And O.Order_status <> 3             -- not a deleted order
        And O.Items > 0                     -- not an empty order
        and O.Chg_date <= dateadd(minute,-5,sysdatetime())
)

select order_id
from Top_order
where row_num = 1;
```

Comment: Pardon, what do all these bears mean?